# Header to cache an HTTP resource and use it if server is not available (ie: offline)?

Tags: http-headers, browser-cache, cache-control

I saw that using `Cache-Control` and `max-age`, I can let a browser cache a web page (and its resource, like CSS, JS, pictures, etc) for a while.

But I would like to do the following:

- No matter what the cache contains, try contacting the server ("normal" behavior)
- If the server responds, use the response from the server (might be a 304)
- If the server does not respond (ie: server down, *or you are offline*  like on mobile), then use what the cache contains (if cache contains nothing, show an error).

I don't really see how this could be achieved using HTTP response headers. Trying `Cache-Control: max-age=3600` caches the response for an hour, and browser just never contact server. And using a `Cache-Control: no-cache` forces the client to contact the server and always return an error if mobile is offline/server is not available.

**What are the HTTP header values to use for the desired behavior (the business goal is to keep the last browser cached version to keep using the website even when offline)?**

Comment: It seems there is no HTTP-header-simple way to do so, besides the not-implements `stale-if-error` (which would actually be great to have). I'll give a try to Service workers instead then https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers

Answer (score 1):

As you suggest in your comment, the solution here would be the [`stale-if-error`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5861#section-4) cache control extension:

> The stale-if-error Cache-Control extension indicates that when an
> error is encountered, a cached stale response MAY be used to satisfy
> the request, regardless of other freshness information.

However, it's unsupported by browsers. The [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=995651) hasn't seen any activity, and the [Chrome work on the related `stale-while-revalidate`](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=348877) was rolled back and abandoned.

At least one CDN supports it (["Fastly - Stale-While-Revalidate, Stale-If-Error Available Today"](https://www.fastly.com/blog/stale-while-revalidate-stale-if-error-available-today/)), although that would obviously only help in the case where your origin server is down, rather than the user lacking a network connection.

Your options for now seem to be doubling down on requiring a working network connection, or using a more involved technique for manual cache management.

Comment: Have a look at service workers maybe. (I commented before seeing that @Xenos suggested that already - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350024/header-to-cache-an-http-resource-and-use-it-if-server-is-not-available-ie-offl#comment77700848_45350024)

Comment: [The issue you linked](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=348877) suggests `stale-while-revalidate` will come with chromium 75. Not `stale-if-error` though.